# python: check dict keys on duplicate value and assign to new dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key, iteration

**Set-up**

I have a dictionary containing districts and postal codes, e.g.

```
d={
 'Center':['A1', 'B1','C1', 'D1'],
 'West':['A1', 'B2','C2', 'D2'],
    ⋮
 'North':['A1', 'B2','C3', 'D3'], 
}
```

---

**Problem**

Some postal codes are in multiple districts, e.g. `A1` is in `Center`, `West` and `North` and `B2` in `West` and `North`.

I want to check which postal codes are in multiple areas, and then create a 'vice-versa' dictionary with these postal codes and districts, i.e.

```
vice_versa = {
 'A1':['Center', 'West', 'North']
   ⋮
 'B2':['West', 'North']
}
```

---

**(Semi)Code so far**

```
vice_versa={}
for key in list(d.keys()):
   for x in d[key]:
       if x in d[~key]: 
           vice_versa[x] = key, ~key
```

There are two issues:

1. How to iterate over the other keys, e.g. if `key='Center'` then how to iterate over `~key='West'` and `~key='North'`.
2. How to assign all keys to `vice_versa`, e.g. how to assign `'Center'`, `'North'` and `'West'` to `vice_versa['A1']`.

For clarity, `vice_versa` should only contain 'duplicate' postal codes, e.g. `A1` and `B2`, and **not** the other postal codes in the example (e.g. not `C1`).

Comment: Do you want to include the postal codes with a single region as well?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, good remark. No, I do not want that. Only the 'duplicate' postal codes. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you describe here, you want some *transpose* of the dictionary. In my opinion you better use a `defaultdict` for this (which is a subclass of `dict` so all dictionary operations are still supported):

```
from collections import defaultdict

vice_versa = defaultdict(list)
for region,postals in d.items():
    for postal in postals:
        vice_versa[postal].append(region)
```

In a second phase, we can filter out the postals with only one region, for instance by using *dictionary comprehension* and turn the result back into a *vanilla* dictionary:

```
vice_versa = {k:v for k,v in vice_versa.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

Based on your sample input, this gives:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in vice_versa.items() if len(v) > 1}
{'B2': ['North', 'West'], 'A1': ['Center', 'North', 'West']}
```

Comment: Genius! Works like a charm. I'll accept the answer when I am allowed.